# String should not contain two consecutive forward slashes and any of the special character except underscore(_) and hyphen (-)

Tags: javascript, regex, safari, regex-lookarounds

Looking for a JS regex which should return false, when the string contains :

1. Two consecutive forward slash, Or/And
2. Any of the special character except hyphen and underscore.

**Note: It should have cross browser compatibility as negative lookahead/lookbehind is not supported in Safari.**

I have tried this regex: `/(^[\w-\/]+$)(?<!.*?\/{2,}.*$)/`
It works for my use case but its not supported in safari, because of the negative lookbehind.

**Expected Behaviour :**

**Can Match any below:**

```
asc/_bsj
acs-h-
acs
acs/bgt
```

**Can't match any below:**

```
acs//
acs/@
acs@
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your pattern without any lookarounds by removing the `/` from the character class, and optionally repeat the allowed characters with a leading forward slash.

```
^(?![\w/-]*\/\/)[\w/-]+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uGWOSb/1)

```js
const regex = /^(?![\w/-]*\/\/)[\w/-]+$/;
[
  "asc/_bsj",
  "acs-h-",
  "acs",
  "acs/bgt",
  "/",
  "a/",
  "acs//",
  "acs/@",
  "acs@",
  "a// "
].forEach(s =>
  console.log(`${s} --> ${regex.test(s)}`)
);
```

Comment: This returns false, even for single slashes, rather it should return true, as only two or more than two consecutive slashes are not allowed

Comment: This one is returning false for empty string, rather it should return true for empty string..
Marking it solved as it fulfills other scenarios.

Comment: @SaurabhShukla If you also want to match empty strings, you can make the quantifier 0 or more times like `^(?![\w/-]*\/\/)[\w/-]*$`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const regex = /\/\/|[!.*?@]/g
const strings = [
'asc/_bsj',
'acs-h-',
'acs',
'acs/bgt',
'acs//',
'acs/@',
'acs@'
]

for (const string of strings) {
  console.log(string, string.match(regex) ? 'no' : 'yes')
}
```

Comment: Good idea on `not(A or B)`. Your regex however incorrectly returns true with other special characters, such as `#`, `&`, `+`. Better to check for not allowed characters using a negated character class

Comment: It's the opposite of what i am expecting.
It should return false for a// and true for a/

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use two regexes, e.g. `regex1 and not regex2`:

```js
[
  'asc/_bsj',
  'acs-h-',
  'acs',
  'acs/bgt',
  'acs//',
  'acs/@',
  'acs@'
].forEach(str => {
  let check = /(^[\w-\/]+$)/.test(str) && !/\/\//.test(str);
  console.log(str, '=>', check);
});
```

Output:

```
asc/_bsj => true
acs-h- => true
acs => true
acs/bgt => true
acs// => false
acs/@ => false
acs@ => false
```

Or you could use a single negated regex:

```js
[
  'asc/_bsj',
  'acs-h-',
  'acs',
  'acs/bgt',
  'acs//',
  'acs/@',
  'acs@'
].forEach(str => {
  let check = !/\/\/|[^\w-\/]/.test(str);
  console.log(str, '=>', check);
});
```

Output:

```
asc/_bsj => true
acs-h- => true
acs => true
acs/bgt => true
acs// => false
acs/@ => false
acs@ => false
```

Comment: Hey
Can't write two Regex, and also i cant check it with !, In my case, it's the regex, who should take care of this.